# Test.setCurrentPage not start the controller constructor?

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-controller

I'm trying to test Apex message at another page. That's my controllers:

**Controller 1**

```
public PageReference GoToPage2()
{
  ApexPages.PageReference pr = new ApexPages.PageReference(Page.Page2);
  pr.SetRedirect(true);
  pr.GetParameters().Put('message', 'Hello, World!');
  return pr;
}
```

**Controller 2**

```
public Controller2(){
      String message = '' + ApexPages.CurrentPage().GetParameters().Get('message');
      String pageHeaderReferer = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer'); 

      // Use the referrer parameter to only show the message when coming from Page 1
      if(pageHeaderReferer != null && pageHeaderReferer.containsIgnoreCase('Page1') && message != 'null')
      {
        ApexPages.CurrentPage().AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, message));
      }
    }
```

and test method

**TEST**

```
Controller1 c1 = new Controller1();

Test.startTest();
    PageReference currentPage = c1.GoToPage2();
    Test.setCurrentPage(currentPage);
    List<Apexpages.Message> msgs = ApexPages.getMessages();
    System.debug(msgs);
Test.stopTest();
```

How is it possible that pagereference not start a default constructor? Is it normal?

--edit

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl()
```

returns a url to redirected page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test methods "don't initialize a full Visualforce stack" (I was told this by an engineer). In other words, you don't get anything "for free," so you must initialize anything that would happen naturally during the transition from one page to another. You have to actually construct a Controller2 class. This is **normal, expected** behavior. Make sure you construct a Controller2, or you won't get the behavior you expect.